# How to uninstall/completely remove the installed third-party themes in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have installed a bunch of themes from a website that contains themes as settings in my Android Studio, and have also changed the **Language Defaults** in **Colors and Fonts**, as well as the font from **Monospaced** to **Myriad Pro**.

After this, my IDE has really, really slowed down.

So how can I uninstall the installed themes?